# Getting elements by className in a React Function Component

Tags: reactjs

For class Components in React, I could use

`ReactDOM.findDOMNode(<instance-of-outermost-component>).getElementsByClassName('snap')`

to get all the elements with className `snap`, but It doesn’t work with function components. How can I get all the elements with the same Classname in function components?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should not really be accessing the DOM like that with React- unless you are using it within a testing framework. But even then you would not be accessing the DOM through ReactDom.

What are you trying to actually do when accessing the classes like that?

To apply changes in React you would want to be using state and then conditionally apply these to components. It seems like you are trying to apply a practice common in vanilla javascript development or even something like jQuery.

I think you would benefit from going through this demo of how state can be used: [react state tutorial](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html)

Answer (score 0):

You probably have 2 options if you *need* to query the DOM, from what I can tell... depending on how your code is structured.

1. **useEffect** or **useLayoutEffect** will likely let you query the DOM in the vanilla javascript ways since they run after render...

**useEffect**
useEffect allows you perform side effects from a function component. When useEffect is called, React knows to render your side effect only after changes are made to the DOM
By default, React runs the effect after every render - including the first render. This is to say that useEffect is effected only after the component is rendered.

**useLayoutEffect**
useLayoutEffect fires synchronously after the DOM mutation and before the browser get to paint the new changes. This hook is especially useful for performing DOM measurement like scroll height, scroll width, scroll position and other style on any DOM element.

Researching these guys is a great way to start...

2. **fowardRef**: forwardRef lets your component expose a DOM node to parent component with a ref. See the docs here: https://react.dev/reference/react/forwardRef

I have used the forwardRef to create a list of DOM elements by ref and then manipulate them like any other response from document.getElementByClassName(), not saying you should but if you need to...

---

**I'm not advocating the use of either for your specific use** and this question is way too old for your problem to persist but it came up while I was trying to solve a similar challenge and didn't like the lease helpful form of answer the other person left...

"You shouldn't," is not an answer, it may be advice worth considering but it's not helpful.

Cheers to future me looking for how to do this! And a 'thank you' to anyone who comes along and provides a more articulate answer.